# IPFS add returns 2 jsons

Tags: ipfs

The add command returns 2 jsons - not yet sure if this is a bug or a feature that I am not aware of:

```
⋊> ~ curl -F "image=@/home/ligi/bar" 127.0.0.1:5001/api/v0/add          00:53:12
{"Name":"bar"}
{"Name":"bar","Hash":"QmbFMke1KXqnYyBBWxB74N4c5SBnJMVAiMNRcGu6x1AwQH"}
```

Unfortunately this then breaks the ipfs-java-api

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A recent commit changed the way the progress flag is handled in add, for now you'll have to explicitly disable progress when making api calls to add.

I did this in the go-ipfs-api recently: https://github.com/ipfs/go-ipfs-api/commit/7c354892da3abdaafb6ac576c100b259b1a73dac